# Undefined error on jQuery.ajax on android/ios

Tags: jquery, ajax

my website uses an ajax request to my rest api, it's working like expected in desktop browser (chrome, ie, ff) and my windows phone. 
With android or ios the xhr response is undefined and its running in the ajax error callback. 
The json response from my restapi is valid, at least jsonlint says so and it is working on desktop.

```
{
  "code": 1,
  "status": 200,
  "data": {
    "menuHome": "START",
    "menuAbout": "UEBER UNS",
    "menuTeam": "DAS TEAM",
    "menuContact": "KONTAKT",
    "menuFindus": "Besucht uns",
    "menuLanguage": "Sprache",
    "pageBannerHeadline": "Start",
    "pageBannerBreadFirst": "Breadfirst",
    "headline": "START",
    "footerTitleLeft": "Linker Titel",
    "footerTextLeft": "DE Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipi sicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna.",
    "footerTitleRight": "Kontaktieren Sie uns",
    "footerTextRight": "So erreichen Sie uns :",
    "footerTelefon": "1234 - 5678 - 9012",
    "footerEmail": "user@mail.de"
  }
}
```

Response is from PHPStorm rest client.
And the ajax request is like following:

```
$.ajax({
        dataType: "json",
        type: "POST",
        url: "https://rest.domain.de/getLanguage.json",
        cache: false,
        data: {
            "username": "foo",
            "password": "bar",
            "lang": lang.toUpperCase(),
            "page": _site.toLowerCase()
        },
        header: {
            'Accept':'*/*',
            'Cache-Control': 'no-cache'
        },
        beforeSend: function (){
             alert("lang : " + lang.toUpperCase() + " page : " + _site.toLowerCase());
            // show loader
        },
        success: function (data) {
            // do something
        },
        error: function (xhr) {
                alert("Error : "+xhr.responseText);
        }
    });
```

Both, lang and _site are filled on mobile. I also tried to add $.support.cors = true; without any effect.

The response Header:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 01 Mar 2016 11:45:11 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.27 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.27 OpenSSL/1.0.1e-fips
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.45
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
```

Im confused as I don't get any responseText to determinate where to have a closer look, maybe someone could help me by pointing in the right direction?

Comment: Where does the undefined error occur?

Comment: additionally, can you tell which method was used on that request that you have headers for? whether it's OPTIONS or GET/POST? (check from console/debugging tools, not your code/console.log)

Comment: The headers are from a request send by phpstorm restclient while method set to POST.

Comment: you'll need to get the headers from the request sent on the mobile device some how. If it's sending an OPTIONS request, and your server isn't handling it appropriately, that would be the cause of the problem.

Comment: The error occur when I retrieve the site on a mobile device. It runs into the error: function() while the responsetext is undefined/empty. So I'm a bit stucked how to debug this error, as I can't tell what's wrong.

Is there any way to get the devtools open on a mobile device?

Comment: depends on the device. but, you could instead do debugging server-side to see what requests reach the server. If your POST route is being reached when you send the request with the mobile device, and you can confirm it returns data in that situation, then it's probably not a CORS problem

Comment: Ok, I set a simple logging to the serverside method and its not reached from mobile. So it seems its a CORS problem?

Comment: Very likely. One possible fix if it was a cors problem would be to implement CORS preflight functionality on your server. The other fix would be to make the ajax request "simpler", by removing any headers that you don't absolutely need. additional headers that cause the request to be "not simple" cause the need for a preflight request. Different browsers/platforms may define "simple request" differently, so it's easier to just make the server support both.

Comment: Ok, I checked for cors support and preflights. 
If I send HEAD, GET or POST its working as expected, while PUT, DELETE and OPTIONS will end in this: 

Fired XHR event: loadstart
Fired XHR event: readystatechange
Fired XHR event: progress
Fired XHR event: error

XHR status: 0
XHR status text: 
Fired XHR event: loadend

I tried adding Preflights to nginx with this: https://michielkalkman.com/snippets/nginx-cors-open-configuration.html

But it didn't work, I'm using a centos webpanel vserver with apache and nginx.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found it.
The problem was a failure in the SSL chain, I renewed the bundle.crt and its working like a charm, so if anyone else has similar problems, maybe consider to have a look at this.

@Kevin-B: Thanks for your time and help.

Answer (score 0):

After many hours of testing I found out why ! It's because of the dataType : json. Remove and it will work like charm! Peace